# Words that shall not be used…

Tags: discussion, feature-request

[Base off the extended discussion on this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/90150/2100). I used the word [idiot](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/idiot) which as the definition shows is "formal". I, mistakenly, believed that this would be fine. It apparently was with a large number of upvotes (↑51, ↓4) but several flag were raised that the answer edited.

*Just to be clear: I have no problem whatsoever in the answer being edited and being called out for using the term. None whatsoever. [mxyzplk](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/140/mxyzplk) has done his job with great professionalism. This is **not** about that.*

Is there a list of words/verbs that shall not be used?

If not, should there be one?

As a non-native speaker, I am sometimes baffled by what some of the members of this site think as offensive. And while offense is generally taken even if it is not intended, I wish to reduce the number of instances where I sound like an insulting cretin<sup>1</sup>.

---

<sup><sub>**1**: I can insult myself right? ☺</sub></sup>

Comment: See also [Appropriateness of word monitoring](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/5770/4398), [Is profanity allowed on RPG.SE?](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/3573/4398), [What is “appropriate”](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/5574/4398), etc.

Comment: It's not the word used in this case, it's that it was used to attack a real person's intelligence, a clear violation of Be Nice.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie: I see how it could be interpreted that way. I was actually referring more to the GM's action which were idiotic -- Or was that inappropriate too?

Comment: There are many ways to attack someone personally. They're all contrary to our conduct policy.

Comment: If you make an error without malice, any of us editing should be able to help with some of the surprises you may encounter, but people who note what comes off as offensive may still comment/flag since they won't know your particular situation.  There are some limits to text based communication, and this is one of them.

Comment: Yes, precisely! No harm, not foul. We just have to mod for the average reader: those who don't know us personally and who we can't expect to adjust for what our intentions are.